# Building a media browser service that loads dynamically the media sources

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-music-player, android-mediasession

I am newbie in the android development.
I am trying to develop an application which needs to play mp3 files in the background.

I read a lot of articles about media browser service and the new architecture approach to develop a media player application.
In my case, the media files will be loaded from a json file, which is depends on the content of the page that the user enters. When the user goes to an activity, the app loads the related information and starts to play the audio files.

If i have understood correctly, the music browser service loads the audio files at the startup and the client can browse the files or controls the playback.
Is that correct?

Can you give me an example how i can load the audio files dynamically in the service?

Comment: `In my case, the media files will be loaded from a json file, ` Does the json file contain the media? That will be a big file.

Comment: Post the code you tried

Comment: @blackapps the json contains the links for the audio files.

Comment: @mehdi i don't have code yet, i want to figure out if the approach with media playback service is suitable for my case.